# ReferenceError for defined variables

Tags: javascript, exception, switch-statement

I'm baffled. I imagine I've tread on some bit of JavaScript esoterica but I don't know what it is.

The code is

```
processMessage(ws, json){
    let msg = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(`Message(${msg.type}): ${msg.data}`);
    console.log("Available games: " + msg.data); // Normally isn't here, put it in to make sure I wasn't going crazy

    switch (msg.type){
        case "welcome":
            console.log("Welcome received. Requesting available games.");
            let msg = {
                "type":"game list",
                "data":null
            };

            ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
            break;
        case "restore":
            break;
        case "game list":
            console.log("Available games: " + msg.data);
            break;
        case "create console":
            break;
    }
}
```

It generates this output

```
Message(welcome): undefined                                                                 MainUI.js:94:21
Available games: undefined                                                                  MainUI.js:95:21
Welcome received. Requesting available games.                                               MainUI.js:98:29
Message(game list): The Office                                                              MainUI.js:94:21
Available games: The Office                                                                 MainUI.js:95:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'msg' before initialization       MainUI.js:109:21
    processMessage http://localhost:8000/MainUI.js:109
    onmessage http://localhost:8000/MainUI.js:44
    loaded http://localhost:8000/MainUI.js:42
    onload http://localhost:8000/:1
```

I'm pretty sure that output has `msg`, or its properties, being accessed 1,2,3...4 times before the error occurs.

Aaaaaand, I just found the cause. Knew it was my fault but there's the esoterica.

Answer (score 0):

Within the switch itself, I put

```
case "welcome":
    console.log("Welcome received. Requesting available games.");
    let msg = {
        "type":"game list",
        "data":null
    };

    ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    break;
```

That second `let msg`, instead of providing an error like `'msg' has already been declared`, somehow confuses the interpreter into thinking that `msg` hadn't yet been declared. Removing `let` and just having `msg =` makes the error go away.

If anyone reads this and has a reference to explain the reason this happens, I'd really appreciate your adding a comment with a link.